# How can I select data where minimum of multiple columns is between a range using Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to select data where the minimum of 3 columns is between a specific range using Laravel Query Builder.

My current code is

```
        ->whereBetween('price_one', [$min, $max])
        ->whereBetween('price_two', [$min, $max])
        ->whereBetween('price_three', [$min, $max])
```

This selects data where all the prices are between $min and $max but I want to select products where the minimum price is between $min and $max.

How do I refactor my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `whereRaw` along with `LEAST()`:

```
whereRaw("LEAST(price_one, price_two, price_three) BETWEEN ? AND ?", [$min, $max])
```